# Extension that only works in a particular object

Tags: swift, polymorphism, where-clause, protocols, extension-methods

I am thinking about an extension that will only work inside a particular object. I don't know if it's possible. Example:

I have a model. This model will get a function on the extension that only works inside a particular class, and it will trigger a method from that class.

Something like this (of course doesn't work but it shows what I want to do):

```
struct DataModel {}

extension DataModel where Self: MyProtocol  {
    func execute() {
        self.start()
    }
}

protocol MyProtocol {
    func start()
}

class Class_A: MyProtocol {
    func start() {
        print("Model extension worked") // Will work
    }
    
    let model = DataModel()
    
    func doSomething() {
        model.execute()
    }
    
}

class Class_B {
    
    let model = DataModel()
    
    func doSomething() {
        model.execute() // Nothing will happen
    }

}
```

So my model extension should work depending on the context without type-checking and entering information about the class. It must detect the "self" and run the method accordingly. How can i do that?

Comment: This is a weird thing to do and might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why not just declare `execute(_ model: DataModel)` in an `extension MyProtocol` instead? Rather than doing `model.execute()`, write `execute(model)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DataModel` is already a definitive type that can't be specified further. The `where` clause would be valid only if the extended type is generic, i.e. could be specified in some way. More specifically, if `DataModel` conforms to `MyProtocol`, it's known at the compile time, there's no room for `where`.

The second questionable thing is that you try to fit `MyProtocol` on `DataModel`'s extension, but below, only classes conform to it.

My best guess is that you mean something like this:

```swift
final class DataModel<EnclosingType: AnyObject> {

    private weak var enclosingObject: EnclosingType? // weak to avoid reference cycles.

    init(enclosingObject: EnclosingType) {
        self.enclosingObject = enclosingObject
    }

}

protocol MyProtocol {
    func start()
}

extension DataModel where EnclosingType: MyProtocol  {
    func execute() {
        enclosingObject?.start()
    }
}

final class ClassA: MyProtocol {

    private lazy var model = DataModel(enclosingObject: self)

    func start() {
        print("Model extension worked")
    }

    func doSomething() {
        model.execute()
    }

}

final class ClassB {

    private lazy var model = DataModel(enclosingObject: self)

    func doSomething() {
        // model.execute() – Nope.
    }

}
```

The thing to keep in mind here is that Swift is strong-typed language, and if the condition `where EnclosingType: MyProtocol` doesn't stand, the method is not available even at the compile time. You don't need to check types, the compiler will just not allow you to use `execute()` (see `ClassB`.)